# What is the 'Meta' key in Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app, macos-mojave

What is the purpose of the 'Meta' key in Terminal.app? I see lots of questions about it, but nothing actually explains what it exists for. I see it as a menu item and on my MacBook's touchbar. Does it exist in any other apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an extra modifier key (like Command, Option/Alt, and Control) that's used in the popular `emacs` text editor because `emacs` author and GNU/FSF founder Richard M. Stallman was accustomed to it from the computers he'd worked on, like Symbolics LISP systems and some custom big iron at MIT.

Because so many people who use terminal emulators use `emacs`,  terminal emulators are expected to have ways to let you press the Meta key.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key